why xpath not worked in priority views?
I am trying to inherit all time off views (Time off --> Management -->Timeoff) for remove create and create and edit option for employees fields .
The employees fields is the many2many fields
I tried like this ,
<record id="hr_leave_view_form_manager_inherit" model="ir.ui.view">
    <field name="model">hr.leave</field>
    <field name="inherit_id" ref="hr_holidays.hr_leave_view_form_manager"/>
    <field name="arch" type="xml">
        <xpath expr="//field[@name='employee_ids']" position="attributes">
            <attribute name="options">{'no_create': True, 'no_open': True}</attribute>
        </xpath>
    </field>
</record>

but it is not working , i tried replace but not working ,
i think the issue with priority . in default the mode is primary and priority is 16.
I am using odoo17 enterprice edition
